# How to stream IPConfig /displaydns

Tags: powershell, ipconfig, batch

Is there a simple way I can have a powershell / cmd prompt open and stream the dns cache so that it will scroll automatically as things are being cached?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the MicrosoftDNS_Cache WMI Class in the root\MicrosoftDNS namespace. My desktop doesn't have that namespace available, but supposedly it's available for servers.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -Class MicrosoftDNS_Cache `
    -ComputerName $RemoteServer
```

That might give you a start in the direction you're looking for.

If that has the data you're looking for, you could wrap that into an endless loop like so:

```
while ( -1 ) {
    Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -Class MicrosoftDNS_Cache `
        -ComputerName $RemoteServer
}
```

Obviously you'll have to tweak the get-wmiobject code to get the output to look how you want, and as mentioned above, that's assuming the class/namespace contain the date you're looking for.